# TypeScript+Protractor : issue with webdriver actions in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, selenium, typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to delete some of the duplicate contacts in an app ([CafeTownsend](http://cafetownsend-angular-rails.herokuapp.com/login)). Those elements are in repeater and below is the function I am using to delete the contacts. It is not executing the browser actions properly.

Full project@ [ProtractorTest](https://github.com/Harshaec021/TypeScriptProject.git)

### Method: deleteAccount

```
deleteAccount(account: Account): void {

                this.LIST_CONTACT.filter((elem, index) => {
                        return elem.getText().then((text) => {
                                return (text == account.fname + ' ' + account.lname);
                        });
                }).then((filteredAccounts) => {
                        console.log(filteredAccounts.length+" accounts are there with "+account.fname);
                        if (filteredAccounts.length !== 0) {

                                filteredAccounts.forEach((elem,index)=>{
                                    console.log('About to delete the contact');

                                elem.click();
                                this.LNK_DELETE_CONTACT.click();
                                browser.switchTo().alert().accept();

                                });
                        }else{
                                console.error(new Error('No such contact to delete'));
                        }
                });


        }
```

### Console output

```
TypeScriptProject>protractor ConvertedJSFiles\config\config.js
[09:23:57] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[09:23:57] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
**********
2 accounts are there with Jimmy
About to delete the contact
About to delete the contact
.**

Pending:

1) Cintact creation should check if contact is created
  Temporarily disabled with xit


2) Cintact creation should delete the selected contact
  Temporarily disabled with xit

3 specs, 0 failures, 2 pending specs
Finished in 18.523 seconds
[09:24:39] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[09:24:39] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Comment: What happens now when you run this code?

Comment: @Xotabu4  Does not click on element to be deleted which in turn does not enable the delete button and alert does not pop up until and unless I click on delete button. So everything's breaking

Comment: I think the question that needs to be answered is where does it fail? Does it print out 'About to delete the contact? If you add a log statement after the `elem.click()` does it print that too? So my advice is more logging and add your console output on the question because it will help us understand what is going on here.

Comment: @cnishina.. Attached the console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to put a workaround for this issue as below.

```
deleteSingleAccount(account: Account): void {

                let filteredAccounts = this.LIST_CONTACT.filter((elem, index) => {
                        return elem.getText().then((text) => {
                                return (text == account.fname + ' ' + account.lname);
                        });
                })

                filteredAccounts.count().then((count) => {
                        console.log(count+' is the new count')
                        for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                                filteredAccounts.get(count-i).click();
                                this.LNK_DELETE_CONTACT.click();
                                browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent,3000);
                                browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
                        }
                });

        }
```